# no module named '_bz2' in virtualenv, python3

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04, bzip2

I'm using **'virtualenv'** to manage different environments. (**ubuntu 18.04**)

But when I workon an env with **python3.7** and run the code(smpl-x from github) , it says "no module named '_bz2'".

I tried these:

1. sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
   But it seems that bz2 is not installed in my virualenv, so it doesn't work.
2. some posts say that I need to rebuild python. But I don't know how to do this in my virtualenv.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where from and how did you install global `python3.7`? Compiled from sources? Installed with `apt`?

Comment: Hello dude I have solved my problem by rebuilding my global python. It was because I'm not familiar with linux that I don't know how to solve this problem. I'm going to practice more. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I have solved this problem.

I removed my global python3.7 and built it again from the source code. Then the problem is solved.

I'm a noob in linux so not very familiar with these operations.

Again very appreciate your attention. Thank you very much!!